# Why does the accuracy of Navmesh Agent Path depend on Moving Object's Acceleration Value?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I use Unity's Navmesh agent to govern the movement of my objects. I am observing a weird behaviour: increasing the acceleration of my object increases the accuracy of the path.

For example, consider the following two objects:

1. Object 1 moves with speed of 15 and acceleration of 30.
2. Object 2 moves with speed of 15 and acceleration of 8.

I instruct both objects to move to the same spot one at a time. Reaching the spot requires the object to make a left turn around a building.

Object 1 reaches destination using a nice tight path while Object 2 makes a weird turn when trying to turn. I've captured these two in the attached GIF.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: I believe the acceleration also effects how quickly the agent will rotate. So a higher acceleration means they'll start turning faster. Would need to check in the documentation though

Comment: Thanks Istalri. I am surprised that my question got 19 views only over a two-day span.  I am sure Unity development is very active. Am I in the right place? Are there better places to ask the questions except Unity Answers which is broken as it does not even allow me to upload images.

Comment: I'm not sure myself I'm afraid, there is some unity activity on stack overflow but I've also noticed it seems to be a less popular tag. It's not that your in the wrong place as its still a perfectly valid question/topic but there might be better forums that are more unity specific. Outside of Unity Answers though, I'm not aware of any.